# Definition of differentiable function $f: U\to\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ be open and $f: U\to\mathbb{R}^n$

$f$ is differentiable in $x\in U$, if holds:

It exists $A:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ linear and $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(x+\xi)=f(x)+A\xi+\varphi(\xi)$ for every $\xi$ in a neighborhood of $0$ with

$\lim_{\xi\to 0\\ \xi\neq 0} \frac{1}{\|\xi\|_2}\varphi(\xi)=0$

Question:

As a note it is stated, that it is sufficient that $\varphi$ is defined in a neighborhood of $0$.

I am acutally not sure why, or what this is supposed to mean.
What would be an (non-trivial) example for a function, which is not defined in a neighborhood of $0$?

Of course $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto 1/x$ is not defined in $0$, and constructing a function, which is not defined in $B_\epsilon(0)$ for $\epsilon>0$ should not be difficult, but I am actually confused.

Can you explain this side note?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: They simply mean that $\varphi$ is not necessarily defined on the whole of $U$, like $f$.

Comment: @Bernard Ah, I see. Hmm, it is kinda odd that this is worth a side note in my opinion. Is there more to it? If not I think I just misunderstood the note.

Comment: No, that's all. Usually, one simply denotes $\varphi(\xi)=o(\|\xi\|)$.

Comment: @Bernard And why is it enough, to define $\varphi$ just in a neighborhood of $0$? I would explain it to me simply, that it does not matter what happens outside of the neigborhood of $0$, which is clear from the definition. Could one formaly proof this?

Comment: Well that's the general way  limits work: properties have to be satisfied in *some* neighbourhood of the point at which we're interested in the limit. I don't think it requires a special proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of such definitions is merely to say that the error
$$f(x+\xi) - [f(x)+A\xi]$$
is small compared to $\|\xi\|_2$ for $\xi$ sufficiently close to $0$. By definition, $\phi(\xi)$ is just this error.

If you want to try to understand it further, consider a function like
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0, & x=0 \\ y, & x\ne 0\end{cases}.$$
If $f$ is differentiable at $0$, what is $A$ and does the error meet this criterion?

Comment: Quick question, because I have seen this notation before. You write just $x=0$ and $x\neq 0$ but you should mean $(x,y)=0$ and $(x,y)\neq 0$ do you? Is this a common notation?

Comment: No, I wrote precisely what I meant. This is a function of $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$. If you prefer, in keeping with your notation, I could write $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x_1=0 \\ x_2, & x_1\ne 0\end{cases},$$ now writing $x=(x_1,x_2)$. I agree that it might be clearer to use $\mathbf x$ or $\vec x$ for the vector variable $x$.

Comment: So you just mean with $x$ an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Got it. A little bit confusing when there are several $x$ involved. Once as element of $\mathbb{R}$ and the other in $\mathbb{R}^2$. (Hope I understand you right now...). Well suppose $f$ is differentiable at $0$, then we have $\underbrace{f(0+\xi)}_{=\xi}=\underbrace{f(0)}_{=0}+A\xi+\varphi(\xi)$. Now I would say, that $A$ has to be the identity matrix $I$. I am not sure what to conclude about the error now. It has to hold, that the limit in the definition equals $0$, but $\frac{1}{\|\xi\|_2}$ is unbounded.

Comment: I have not seen the edit, unfortunatly, so I missunderstood the notation... I try again.

Comment: For $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2)$ we should get $f(0+\xi)=f(0)+A\xi+\varphi(\xi)$. With the definition of $f$, we get $\xi_2=A\xi+\varphi(\xi)$. Again $A$ should be $I$. Then the error has to cancel out the $\xi_1$ part and the condition that the limit tends to $0$ should not meet the criterion?

Comment: No, note that $f$ is $0$ along both axes (i.e., $f(x_1,0) = f(0,x_2) = 0$ for all $x_1,x_2$). What does this say about $A$?

Comment: That $A$ has to be $0$?

Comment: Yes, that is the only option ...

Comment: So we would have $f(\xi)=\varphi(\xi)$ but $f(\xi)$ does not vanish in general. Only along the axes. And $A=0$ is the only option, because it is the only linear function, that can hold the property.

Comment: Note that you do not need $\phi(\xi)$ to vanish for all $\xi$. You only need it to be small compared to $\|\xi\|_2$.

Comment: Sorry, I need to slow down... I do not know why this gives me such a struggle... Of course since $f(\xi)=\varphi(\xi)$, we get $\lim_{\xi\to 0\\ \xi\neq 0} \frac{\varphi(\xi)}{\sqrt{\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2}}=\lim_{\xi\to 0\\ \xi\neq 0} \frac{\xi_2}{\sqrt{\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2}}=\lim_{\xi\to 0\\ \xi\neq 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\xi_1^2}{\xi_2^2}+1}}$. But this limit does not exist. For example, if $\xi_1=\xi_2$ (and $\xi\to 0$) we simply get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ as the limit.

Comment: Correct. By the way, you may find the videos linked in my profile helpful as you progress through multivariable calculus/analysis. Good luck!